# Can I send plain text passwords through RabbitMQ?

Tags: security, rabbitmq, rpc

If I have micro-services communicating over RPC through RabbitMQ, is it safe to send secure info (Passwords etc) in plain text in this way?

I assume so because any 'hacker' would need to gain access to my server in order to read the messages, in which case I'd be in trouble anyway, but I'd just like clarification from the security experts out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have also to consider client side applications.

I think that it is never save to send secure info in plain text, unless you have a secure network client side and server side.

You could use https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html or use some crypto library as https://nacl.cr.yp.to/stream.html

Answer (score 2):

> If I have micro-services communicating over RPC through RabbitMQ, is it safe to send secure info (Passwords etc) in plain text in this way?

no.

it's never safe to send passwords or other secure info in plain text, anywhere, for any reason, with any technology.

the only safe way to send passwords and secure info is with some sort of encryption.